# Must See Conference Videos for Python/Django Developers

Tags: python, django, video, conference

There's lots of good conference videos online regarding Python and Django development.

Instead of watching ST:TNG at the computer, I figure it'd more productive to hone my knowledge . Fire away with some of your most inspiring and educational Python, Django, or simply programming related talks. Provide an explanation of why you found the talk useful.

Examples:

[James Bennet on Re-usable Apps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-S0tqpPga4) - Got me to take a serious look at django apps. Put together a fairly robust site in two days afterwards with django-cms, django-photologue, django-contact-form. Good advice on when your app is crossing boundaries and why it's good to err on the site of 'make it a separate app.'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064/the-best-django-webcasts-videos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[blip.tv's pycon channel](http://pycon.blip.tv/) has all talks from Pycon 2009 and (recently concluded) 2010 -- **seriously** good stuff!  Pick your talks from the ["episodes archive"](http://pycon.blip.tv/posts?view=archive&nsfw=dc) pages.

Answer (score 3):

http://pyvideo.org/
Python related video indexed so you can find it. 803 videos so far.

http://lanyrd.com, tag Django

- 157 videos
- 110 slide decks

and updating...

Search for the u'r favorite author, recommeded

- pydanny
- jacobian
- jtaubber

Answer (score 0):

I've found some of the google tech talks on Python or Django very informative.
They have quite a few, so doing a search on "Django" or "Python" at the following website might be a good idea.

http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleTechTalks

Answer (score 0):

When I was looking for online Django tutorial videos, I stumbled across http://showmedo.com/learningpaths/20/view. Nice community developed video tutorial site, which lays out step by step approach to learning. Some of the videos are posted 2 or 3 years before, so the material may not be latest. Nevertheless, it may help you with understanding the fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

In the same vain as the answer from Alex, Djangocon has videos up on blip. http://blip.tv/djangocon